# Cedar tree bark damaged by storm

Tags: wind-damage

cedar tree was damaged by storm.  Large section torn off.  Can I reattach the bark with duct tape and help it to heal?  I can cut the branches and just leave the bark and tape it back to tree.
Please help.

Comment: Please send a picture.  I like how you are thinking with duct tape.  Need an ID on the plant and to be able to see the damage.

Comment: If you want to try this, do it immediately, as quickly as possible, because if its going to work, it needs to be fairly immediate. Its worth a try - if the branches are large and heavy, they'll have to be removed first, but if they're fairly light, leave then in place for the time being. You may need to use a couple of canes, wood struts or sticks to provide extra support (think splints).